# Bad substitution

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I am writting a shell script which will monitor the folder "/home/Folder" and it will call the script.py when it found the file format 1234567.csv file.

```bsh
inotifywait -m --format '%f' -e create /home/Folder | while read FILE
do
   echo "$FILE is created"
   if [[ "${FILE: -11}" == "1234567.csv"]]
   then
       echo "correct format"
       python /home/Folder/script.py
   else
       echo "NOT correct format"
   fi
done
```

However I got "Bad substitution" error and if-else condition does not execute.
May I know is this the correct way of checking whether the FILE's last 11 digit is the same as 1234567.csv? `[[ "${FILE: -11}" == "1234567.csv"]]`

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) `(error): You need a space before the ]].`

Comment: I got the same error after adding a space before ]].

Comment: Btw, instead of hard-coding the number of characters you want to extract, you could use `${FILE##*/}` to get the file name. Your script will also match files named `something_1234567.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a white space within the end of the test - `"1234567.csv"]]`, it should be:

```
[[ "${FILE: -11}" == "1234567.csv" ]]
```

To find such simple mistakes you can use `shellcheck` [online](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ot you can install it via `apt` and then do:

```
shellcheck script.sh
```

Note: It is important to place the correct [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the beginning of the script. It tells the current shell in which *language* the script must be interrelated.

Currently you are using some Bash features - as the double bracket test (type `help [[` and `help [` to see the difference) so you must specify `#!/bin/bash` as shebang.

If the shebang is `#!/bin/sh` you need to rewrite your scrip in Dash/Sh syntax. If the script was pure Python3 the shebang must be `#!/usr/bin/python3` or for more portability `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

If the shebang is missing the script may work within your shell in case it is a Bash script and your shell is Bash - but it will fail, for example, within `crontab` because by default it uses `/usr/bin/sh` as shell.

Comment: I still got the same error of Bad substitution after adding white space after "1234567.csv"

Comment: Hi, @Susan, does there a shebang `#!/bin/bash` in the beginning of the script file?

Comment: ```Line 6:
   if [[ "${FILE: -11}" == "context.csv" ]]
      ^-- SC3010 (warning): In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.
          ^-- SC3057 (warning): In POSIX sh, string indexing is undefined.```

Comment: That is a warning. POSIX / `sh` (in Ubuntu `dash`) doesn't know about `[[`. You need to use `bash` or simply (better) use POSIX style: `[ "$var" = "value" ]` format (single brackets and single equal sign

Comment: Not sure why  the online shellcheck mention, [[ ]] is undefined

Comment: @pa4080, At the beginning I use #!/bin/sh. May I know is should be #!/bin/bash?

Comment: Change either to `bash` **or** (better) use `[ "${FILE##*/}" = "1234567.csv" ]`

Comment: @Susan, as pLumo said, `[[` is a Bash feature so you need to specify it is a `#!/bin/bash` script, no matter the extension of the file is .sh.

Comment: Thank you @pa4080, It is  okay after changing #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash.

Comment: @Susan, great! :)

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168255/is-test-or-or-more-portable-both-between-bash-shells-and-between-other-shel?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @pLumo. The website is really helpful. By the way I tried with  ```[ "${FILE##*/}" = "1234567.csv" ]``` However, it does not execute the if condition even the filename's last 11 digit is matched with 1234567.csv

Comment: This will match the **whole** file name. Of course if you don't want that, you can still use `[ "${FILE: -11}" = "context.csv" ]`